# get values from firestore query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function:

```
 firestore.collection('customers').doc(userID).collection('subscriptions')
.where('status', 'in', ['trialing', 'active']).get()
  .then(activeSubscriptions => {


    // if this is true, the user has no active subscription.
    if (activeSubscriptions.empty === true) {
      console.log("line 31")
      {signOut(props.history)}
      subStatus = "inactive"
    } 
  });
```

Basically, in firestore, I have a customers collection, a doc with the user id, and then the subscriptions collection in which is created upon a user processing stripe. In the subscriptions collection, it has a doc which is the subscription id, and I have some fields I want to grab. See the attached picture:
[image]

I want to grab the `current_period_end` data so I can put it out on screen. how would I do this?

Comment: If you have only activeSubscriptions then you can use activeSubscriptions.data().current_period_end to get that data.

Comment: @suppa98 unfortunately that didn't work. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to access fields from a firestore document, you can do it by specifying the field in square brackets.

With a firestore structure like `/customer/cus123/subscriptions/sub123` I was able to obtain a timestamp field of `sub123` with this code:

```
let cusRef = db.collection('customer').doc('cus123').collection('subscriptions').doc('sub123');

cusRef.get()
.then(doc => {
  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
  } 
  else 
  {
    console.log('Name: ',doc.data()['name']);
    console.log('Tmsp: ',doc.data()['tmsp123']);
  }
});
```

I hope you find this useful.